# Azure VM - Windows Server 2016 Datacenter - Windows Update - There were some problems installing updates (0x8024000e)

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I keep getting the error:

> There were some problems installing updates, but we'll try again
>   later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact
>   support for information, this may help: (0x8024000e)

[image]

The first thing I did was look at this guide:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-updates-fail-with-the-error-code/60e4b742-31f0-457b-b78e-a9c28e411017

The Windows Update troubleshooter does not work and gives me this error:

[image]

[image]

I then tried to fix `Potential Window Update Database error detected` and found this thread:

https://www.kapilarya.com/potential-windows-update-database-error-in-windows-10

Tried running:

`Sfc /scannow` and `Dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` (`Repair-WindowsImage -Online -RestoreHealth`)  but I still got an error.

Sfc message, same message all the time:

> Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.
>
> Beginning verification phase of system scan. Verification 100%
>   complete.
>
> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully
>   repaired them. Details are included in the CBS.Log
>   windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note
>   that logging is currently not supported in offline servicing
>   scenarios.

CBS.log:

```
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    00006497@2020/1/26:22:15:15.699 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    00006498 [SR] Verify complete
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    00006499 [SR] Repairing 1 components
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    0000649a [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    0000649b Hashes for file member \??\C:\Windows\SysWOW64\NlsData0000.dll do not match actual file [l:15]'NlsData0000.dll' :
  Found: {l:32 sZ6yoUz22aVy1eswRaJRyr1MtAsXtbvHB7dHSFFFh3g=} Expected: {l:32 VqGFDDtNkUJL2y72172gbrdibqg7T6Y8qeCjl1AgmkA=}
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    0000649c [SR] Repairing corrupted file \??\C:\Windows\SysWOW64\NlsData0000.dll from store
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    0000649d File [l:15]'NlsData0000.dll' in [l:23]'\??\C:\Windows\SysWOW64' switching ownership
    Old: Microsoft-Windows-NaturalLanguage6-base, version 10.0.14393.2273, arch x86, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}
    New: Microsoft-Windows-NaturalLanguage6-base, version 10.0.14393.2273, arch Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    0000649e@2020/1/26:22:15:15.839 Primitive installers committed for repair
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    0000649f [SR] Repair complete
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    000064a0 [SR] Committing transaction
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    000064a1 Creating NT transaction (seq 2), objectname '(null)'
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    000064a2 Created NT transaction (seq 2) result 0x00000000, handle @0xab4
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    000064a3@2020/1/26:22:15:15.917 Beginning NT transaction commit...
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    000064a4@2020/1/26:22:15:15.964 CSI perf trace:
CSIPERF:TXCOMMIT;33643
2020-01-26 23:15:15, Info                  CSI    000064a5 [SR] Verify and Repair Transaction completed. All files and registry keys listed in this transaction  have been successfully repaired
2020-01-26 23:15:35, Info                  CBS    Session: 30790806_569525021 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent, external staging directory: (null), external registry directory: (null
2020-01-26 23:15:35, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2020-01-26 23:15:35, Info                  CBS    Failed to OpenPackage using worker session [HRESULT = 0x800f0805]
2020-01-26 23:15:35, Info                  CBS    Session: 30790806_569525022 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent, external staging directory: (null), external registry directory: (null
2020-01-26 23:15:35, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2020-01-26 23:15:35, Info                  CBS    Failed to OpenPackage using worker session [HRESULT = 0x800f0805]
```

I then tried running the following sequence and rebooted the server but the error was still present.

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop cryptSvc
net stop bits
net stop msiserver
Ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
Ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
net start wuauserv
net start cryptSvc
net start bits
net start msiserver
```

Lastly I tried to reset Windows Update components manually that was recommended in Method 2. I know it applies to Windows 10 and because of this some errors were expected. After reboot the error was still present.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-resources

[image]

I would not like to use a System Restore point but I soon dont see another way. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran `Sfc /scannow` a second time without reboot and then it actually started working again. Can't tell exactly what fixed it. Another thing to try is stopping `wuauserv` (Windows Update service), remove everything from `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download` and then started `wuauserv` again.

Answer (score 1):

The system might be completely healthy, just running out of RAM. On my test VM (clean Server 2016 Datacenter Core install from official media) I had to increase the maximum memory to 5 GB to avoid the `0x8024000e` error. Someone in another forum [had similar experience](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/12021/azure-vm-windows-update-error-0x8024000e.html) with an Azure B-series VM.

Comment: reset windows update service did not work for me, change RAM size from 5G to 6G worked. noticed windows ram usage goes to 5.X GB afer update service started.